# Angular ng-click not redirecting to the controller template URL

Tags: angularjs

I have a html file `login.html` which contains the ng-click and function for which is writted in login controller. I wish to open a modal on click.Below is my code.

**login.controller:**

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('pb.login').controller('LoginCtrl','$uibModal', function($log, NavigationResolve,$uibModal ) {

    var _this = this;

    _this.navdata = NavigationResolve;


    $scope.OpenModal = function() {
        $uibModal.open({
            size : 'lg',
            templateUrl : '<div>' + 'Hi' + '</div>',
           controller : ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) { $scope.close = function() {
          $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); }; }]

         })
      }; 


  });

})();
```

**login.html**

```
 <div class="row">
            <p class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
               <a href="" ng-click="OpenModal()"> Not a registered user? </a><a href="#" class="">Sign up now</a>
            </p>
        </div>
```

I want to open a model on ng-click. The console is also not thorwing any error. Any help or instructions on why this is not working will be appreciated.

Comment: As the name ```templateUrl``` denotes it should be a path and not ```HTML``` elements..

Comment: I have tried with the path also.

Answer (score 0):

How do you doing the connection with login page and controller? ng-controller or with routeProvider? sometimes the browser not throwing any error is because not exist any connection with the controller and you have an error with the injection in the controller, change to

```
 angular.module('pb.login').controller('LoginCtrl', 
  function($log, NavigationResolve,$uibModal, $scope ) {
     //your code
 })
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was LoginCtrl -Angularjs Argument is not a function got string. Once I removed `'$uibModal'` and defined `$scope` it was working as expected.

```
angular.module('pb.login').controller('LoginCtrl', function($log, NavigationResolve,$uibModal,$scope )
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't taken `$scope` as dependency injection into the controller

```
angular.module('pb.login').controller('LoginCtrl','$uibModal','$scope', function($log, NavigationResolve,$uibModal, $scope ) {

    var _this = this;

    _this.navdata = NavigationResolve;


    $scope.OpenModal = function() {
        $uibModal.open({
            size : 'lg',
            templateUrl : '<div>' + 'Hi' + '</div>',
           controller : ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) { $scope.close = function() {
          $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); }; }]

         })
      }; 


  });
```

Comment: can you please tell the reason behind the downvote?